# Change of coordinates with glFrustum

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl, 3d, openframeworks

I am trying to use `glFrustum` for a perspective projection and as I understand `glFrustum` like `glOrtho` can be used to modify the mapping of our desired coordinate system to real screen coordinates (as read in Blue book). So, if I do 
`glFrustum(-1,1,-1,1,1,1000);`, it changes the coordinates to 
left = -1, right = 1, bottom = -1, top = 1 in the form of cartesian coordinates.

I tried to draw a simple room (with 2 side walls) in this coordinate system by calling the following function in my draw method and it comes out drawing appropriately on the screen.

```
void drawRoomWalls(){
    //Left wall
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(-1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(-1.0, 1.0, -0.4);
    glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, -0.4);
    glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0);
    glEnd();

    //Right wall
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, -0.4);
    glVertex3f(1.0, -1.0, -0.4);
    glVertex3f(1.0, -1.0, 0.0);
    glEnd();
}
```

The function was called as follows:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1000.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0, 0, -1.0);
drawRoomWalls();
```

Subsequently, I tried to do an off-axis projection (by taking mouse as input instead of user's head). The code is as follows:
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPushMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();

```
double fov, near, far;
double headX, headY, headZ;
float aspectRatio;

near = 0.5f; far = 1000.0f;  aspectRatio = ofGetWidth()/ofGetHeight();
fov = tan(DEG_TO_RAD * 30/2); //tan accepts angle in radians. tan of the half of the fov angle
fov = 0.5; //taken constant for now

double msX = (double)ofGetMouseX();
double msY = (double)ofGetMouseY();
double scrWidth = (double)ofGetWidth();
double scrHeight = (double)ofGetHeight();

headX = (msX / scrWidth) - 0.5; 
headY = ((scrHeight - msY) / scrHeight) - 0.5;
headZ = -2.0;

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum( near * (-fov * aspectRatio + headX),
               near * (fov * aspectRatio + headX),
               near * (-fov + headY),
               near * (fov + headY),
               near,
               far);

leftValue = near * (-fov * aspectRatio + headX); //for printing out on screen
rightValue = near * (fov * aspectRatio + headX); //for printing out on screen
bottomValue = near * (-fov + headY); //for printing out on screen
topValue = near * (fov + headY); //for printing out on screen

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(headX * headZ, headY * headZ, 0, headX * headZ, headY * headZ, -1, 0, 1, 0);
glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, headZ);
drawRoomWalls();
```

I printed the values of `leftValue`, `rightValue`, `bottomValue`, `topValue` and when the mouse is in the center of the screen (the call to `glFrustum` looks like `glFrustum(-0.25,0.25,-0.25,0.25,1.0,1000.0)`
As per the above call, I expected the coordinate system's `left=-0.25, right=0.25, bottom=-0.25, top=0.25` and I was expecting the walls to disappear (since they are draw at (1.0,1.0,0.0) for an example). However, the walls keep on appearing on the sides of the screen (with the scene being skewed and at the center being essentially the same as with off-axis projection). Why is it that the walls are still at the place on the sides (even though the coordinates changed to -0.25,0.25) or there's something in glFrustum call that I am missing here about the coordinate system?

Comment: Your values can't be correct. The fact that `left == bottom` and `right == top` implies that `aspectRatio = 1` (since `headX` and `headY` are 0). You set `fov` to `0.5`. That would mean that `near == 0.5`. However, you set it to `1`. There must be some different values than you expect. Please check, if all variables contain correct values.

Comment: @NicoSchertler : I made headX and headY as zero and took a screenshot. -> http://i.imgur.com/dTjfazb.png Well spotted. Aspect ratio indeed was coming out to be one because I wasn't doing doing the type casting to double for division of width/height. Can you add this as answer? I'll ask some follow up questions in those comments. Thanks

Comment: If you think that is the answer, I'll do so.

Comment: I just spotted that you mentioned `glPushMatrix()` calls. Are they somewhere in the code? If so, where are the calls to `glPopMatrix()`?

Comment: @NicoSchertler : glPopMatrix() is done after the `drawRoomWalls()` function in the program (not mentioned here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just realized that you also changed `headZ` to `-2`. That explains the behaviour.

If the camera is situated at `z = 2` and you have a vertical half fov of 0.5, then at `z = 0` you already see 1 unit in positive and negative y-direction. That's why you see the walls.

[image: Visualization]

Comment: Thanks! For that figure especially!